# C: Passing an array of pointers to structs as an argument

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, struct

This question may well have already been answered so I will explain very simply:

I have defined a "list" structure. In a separate function I have initialised an array called "table":

```
int table_size = 500;
struct list* table[table_size];
```

This will store pointers to these "list" structures.
Later in the function I pass this table to another function as the third argument:

```
generate(word, table_size, table);
```

This "generate" function is defined in the following way:

```
void generate(char *str, int table_size, struct list* table)
```

And when I try to compile, I get the following error:

passing argument 3 of ‘generate’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]

note: expected ‘struct list *’ but argument is of type ‘struct list **’

Thanks to anyone who can explain what's going wrong.

Comment: C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays and doesn't need the `struct` keyword when in variable declarations. Please use the correct language tag only.

Comment: Learn basic language concepts from books, not from trial-and-error-and-stack-overflow.

Comment: Ok this also works, so I just always have to add empty square brackets when passing an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your generate function has the wrong type. Try

```
void generate(char *str, int table_size, struct list** table)
```

or

```
void generate(char *str, int table_size, struct list* table[])
```

Comment: Thanks, this does make sense, I think my knowledge of C syntax is patchy which means I end up making mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error message: Change the parameter to be of type `struct list **`.

Comment: Ok yeah that does work, although I'm not really sure why that works, where is the double asterisk coming from in the first place?

Comment: An array is implicitly convertible to a pointer to its first element, that's where the second `*` comes from. Look up "array-to-pointer decay" for more info.

Comment: Ok yeah that does make sense to me now, I will look that up as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of table is an array of struct list pointers. It is compiled as a pointer to a pointer of struct list. Declare table like this:

```
struct list table[table_size]
```

I am assuming you want an array of struct list. Follow the above answers if otherwise.